# Firebase request to return boolean

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I work under angular and in my department I try to make a request to add an ID in a table of a document.

Before that I have to check that the ID does not exist in the table, to avoid duplicates.

For this I need a first request that would send me a boolean I get only objects `AngularFirestoreCollection<unknown>`.

[image]

```
  usePromoCode(userId: string, promoCode: string) {

    this.firestore.collection('promoCode').doc(promoCode).get().switchMap(res => {
      return of(null)
    })

    let bool: boolean = this.firestore.collection('promoCode', ref => ref
      .where('uid', '==', promoCode)
    );

  }
```

I started by trying this but nothing works, I don’t know how to do it...

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Clarifying to see if I understood the issue correctly: What you want to do is query the `promocode` document to check if it's `usedBy` array field is populated with an specific id, is that it? It does not make sense for it to be in the `promoCode` variable, since that is the id of the document itself, not the one to be stored in the array, am I correct? If so, where is the value of the ID you want to check stored?